# Django Queryset annotate() increase date in number of months from another field

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

The problem I have is the following:

Problem: I need to calculate a coupon end-of-use date and for this I have to use the coupon redemption date and the number of months the coupon grants.

```
class Coupon(...):
    ...
    numMonths -> int
    ...

class CouponUses(..):
    ...
    redeemDate -> datetime
    coupon -> FK Coupon
    ...
```

I tried:

1 - Create a property in the CouponUses model to calculate the sum of `redeemDate + relativeDelta (months = self.coupon.numMonths)` which works but not in the queryset.

2 - Try directly annotate on CouponUses queryset `ExpressionWrapper (F ('redeemDate') + relativeDelta (months = F ('coupon__numMonths'))` and neither. However, the problem only happens when I try to use the value of months from the field `numMonths`, if I put a value directly it works.

Comment: What happens with `F('coupon__numMonths')` instead?

Comment: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'F'